# Monotouch Dialog: Getting SimpleMultilineEntryElement to respect its 'size'

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am using a SimpleMultilineEntryElement in MonotouchDialog, from the Elements Pack ([here](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-element-pack)).

Regardless of the height setting, this element continued to appear at the 'default' table cell height.  The actual editable part varied, but the background cell outline did not.  Much browsing indicated a SizingSource needed to be implemented, and I've done that.  So, using a pretty brittle workaround I can now resize cells selectively.  Using the UnevenRows property on the Root element did not help.  Trying to get the cell at that index killed the app, even though indexes were definitely being returned.

- Is there a way to just make it use the height properties I defined for the Multiline entryelement?

  using System;
  using System.Drawing;
  using MonoTouch.Dialog;
  using MonoTouch.Foundation;
  using MonoTouch.UIKit;
  using ElementPack;
  using System.Collections.Generic;

  namespace MyNameSpace
  {
      // Edit existing project or add one if none exists

  public partial class ProjectEdit : DialogViewController
  {
      Project _p;
      UINavigationController _nc;

  ```
  public ProjectEdit (Project p, UINavigationController nc) : base(null, true)
  {
      _p = p;
      _nc = nc;

      if (_p == null)
      {
          _p = new Project();
          _p.InitialiseProjectDefaults();
      }

  }

  public override Source CreateSizingSource (bool unevenRows)
  {
      //if (unevenRows)
      {
          return new unevenSizingSource(this);
      }
  }

  public class unevenSizingSource : DialogViewController.SizingSource
  {
      public unevenSizingSource(DialogViewController vc) : base (vc)
      {

      }

      public override float GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
      {
          // workaround to resize selectively

          // location
          if (indexPath.Section == 1 && indexPath.Row == 0)
          {
              return 200;
          }
          // description
          if (indexPath.Section == 2 && indexPath.Row == 0)
          {
              return 200;
          }

          return 200;
      }
  }

  public override void ViewDidLoad ()
  {
      base.ViewDidLoad ();


  }

  public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
  {
      base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

      // Client selection
      ClientListViewController cl = new ClientListViewController(_nc, _p);

      var basicDetailsSection = new Section("Client") {
          new StringElement(_p.ClientDisplayName, delegate { _nc.PushViewController(cl, true); })
          //new UIViewElement ("", new GapElement (), true)
      };

      var locationSection = new Section("Location") {
          new SimpleMultilineEntryElement ("", "This is the\n location.") { Editable = true, Height = 200,  } 
      };

      var descSection = new Section ("Job Description"){
          new SimpleMultilineEntryElement ("", "This is the\n description") { Editable = true, Height = 200 } 
      };

      Root = new RootElement ("Project Details") {
          basicDetailsSection, locationSection, descSection
      };

  }
  ```

  }

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must set Root.UnevenRows before view appeared. Controller example -

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Dialog;
using ElementPack;

namespace Test1
{
    public class Test2ViewController : DialogViewController
    {
        public Test2ViewController (): base(new RootElement("test"))
        {
            Root.UnevenRows = false;

            Root.Add (new Section () 
                      {
                        new SimpleMultilineEntryElement(string.Empty, "value")
                        {
                            Height = 150, Editable = true
                        },
                        new SimpleMultilineEntryElement(string.Empty, "value2")
                        {
                            Height = 250, Editable = true
                        }});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, Igor!  I ended up finding several issues that may help others - 1) If your MT Dialog is slightly out of date, this resizing doesn't work so get the latest from git. 2) Don't inadvertently leave your sizingsource code present in the vc class or your fixes won't work, 3) Clean and rebuild to make any changes in reference effective.